# Sending image from android to java Server which is running Restful webservice?

Tags: android, xml, json, image, rest

What is the best way to send **image from Android to Java Server**
My Server is running **Restful Web service** and i want to send image from Android to my Server.

should i convert it into JSON, XML or there is any better way of doing this?

**i actually want to send image in a fast way**
plz share if you have any sample code

Comment: convert image to byte array then encode byte array by using Base64  that will return string then u can send the image as string it is a fast way as send image as string

Comment: Thanks @prasad.gai for answer: can u tell me how i will convert this string into image on server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i]/**
     * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format.
     * 
     * @param s
     *            a Base64 String to be decoded.
     * @return An array containing the decoded data bytes.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static byte[] decode(String s)
    {
        return decode(s.toCharArray());
    }

    /**
     * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format. No blanks or line breaks are
     * allowed within the Base64 encoded data.
     * 
     * @param in
     *            a character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
     * @return An array containing the decoded data bytes.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static byte[] decode(char[] in)
    {
        int iLen = in.length;
        if (iLen % 4 != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Length of Base64 encoded input string is not a multiple of 4.");
        while (iLen > 0 && in[iLen - 1] == '=')
            iLen--;
        int oLen = (iLen * 3) / 4;
        byte[] out = new byte[oLen];
        int ip = 0;
        int op = 0;
        while (ip < iLen)
        {
            int i0 = in[ip++];
            int i1 = in[ip++];
            int i2 = ip < iLen ? in[ip++] : 'A';
            int i3 = ip < iLen ? in[ip++] : 'A';
            if (i0 > 127 || i1 > 127 || i2 > 127 || i3 > 127)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
            int b0 = map2[i0];
            int b1 = map2[i1];
            int b2 = map2[i2];
            int b3 = map2[i3];
            if (b0 < 0 || b1 < 0 || b2 < 0 || b3 < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
            int o0 = (b0 << 2) | (b1 >>> 4);
            int o1 = ((b1 & 0xf) << 4) | (b2 >>> 2);
            int o2 = ((b2 & 3) << 6) | b3;
            out[op++] = (byte) o0;
            if (op < oLen)
                out[op++] = (byte) o1;
            if (op < oLen)
                out[op++] = (byte) o2;
        }
        return out;
    }[/i]
```

thanks to this post: http://www.coderanch.com/t/482256/java/java/Converting-Base-encoded-String-Image

Comment: what is map2 array in the above snippet? it is not defined anywhere